# Send Post request to service using certificate

Tags: c#, soap, x509certificate, cryptoapi

I am doing automatic file upload from the service. Some files can be downloaded using the public API, some using the private API. The private API wants to use certificates from me. On the site developer’s site there is software that does the same manipulations, but there is no automatic download. And this software requires in the settings to specify a nugget of the certificate (34.10-2012) that goes with it. It also requires for private functions to specify the personal certificate that I have.

In my program, I get a personal certificate and send a request, but the service responds with an `Internal Server Error (500)`. As I understand it, you must also somehow indicate the root certificate nugget as it requires their software. Should the client use 2 certificates when sending? I can not understand. Previously did not use certificates. Therefore have difficulty

```
public async Task CallWebService()
{
    var _url = "http://xxxxxx.ru:7081/PersonalApi/PersonalApiService.svc/ByCertificate";
    var _action =  "http://xxxxx.ru/soft/dssi/XXXX/XXX/Web/Api/PersonalApi/IPersonalApiService/TestAuthentication";

    XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = CreateSoapEnvelope();
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(_url, _action);

    var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    X509CertificateCollection certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, "2C1EC4D41005000071B0", false);
    webRequest.ClientCertificates = certs;
    InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelopeXml, webRequest);
    try
    {
        var response = await webRequest.GetResponseAsync();
        string soapResult;
        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
        }
        Console.Write(soapResult);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"but the service gives an error"* - and what error would that be?

Comment: Internal service error (500)